# Adding number at specific position in matrix

Tags: python, list, matrix, insert

[Please refer this link for code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7IQE.png)

It is not working, saying 'List index out of range'
I am a beginner, is there correct use of the function or not?
Is there any way to correct the solution or do we need to find another solution?
Thank you!

Comment: Insert method is used to add a new element in the list. If you want to replace the value you should do it like: final_row[row-1][column-1] = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to change an element use

```
final_row[row - 1][column - 1] = your number here
```

You can also check if the row already exists or if you have to create it

```
if (len(final) < row) #Check if row exists
   final_row[row - 1][column - 1] = 0
else:
   final_row.append([1,1,1]) #append a row
   final_row[row - 1][column - 1] = 0
```

Comment: the moment you do `final[row-1]` will trigger an index out of range error if `row-1` is bigger or equal than the number of elements of `final`.

Comment: Thanks for the input changed the answer

Comment: keeps throwing me index out of range exceptions